# How can I start and bind to a service in Android?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I am trying to start a `Service` in `Android`:

```
Log.d("BLE", "Start Service");
Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(gattServiceIntent);
Log.d("BLE", "Service Started");
```

In the `BluetoothLeService` I override the `onStartCommand()` function which means I would see the `log` when the service is started

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
   ....  
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d("BLE", "onStartCommand");
      return START_STICKY;
}
```

However the `log` is the following:

```
07-14 21:30:23.676: D/BLE(28327): Start Service
07-14 21:30:23.676: D/BLE(28327): Service Started
```

but the `onStartCommand()` never appeared in the `log`. How can I start the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to bind to the service first and then start it. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService) says:

*A bound service is one that allows application components to bind to it by calling bindService() in order to create a long-standing connection (and generally **does not allow** components to start it by calling startService())*.

The [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#LifecycleCallbacks) of a service created by calling *bindService()* has different callback methods compare to the one created by calling *startService()* (see the flow diagram on the page provided). So for the service created with a *bindService()* call there is no *onStartCommand()* method, that's why it's never called.

The common practice is to start a service first and after that bind to it (*all the hook methods must be appropriately implemented in this case*). If you do it this way *onStartCommand()* will be called.

**EDIT:**

*How can I start the service?*

You did start the service. After calling *bindService()* it is running (*of course if onBind() is properly implemented with IBinder returned*).

*... but the onStartCommand newer appeared in the log*

It is so due to the reason described above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared BluetoothLeService in the manifest?

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BluetoothLeService" />
```

A service will bot be runnable unless declared i manifest.

Also: are you sure you want to call both bind and start service?

```
bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(gattServiceIntent);
```

it is possible but rather uncommon..

Comment: It is declared in the manifest, otherwise it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the Toast and try again.  That may be the source of your crash.

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: That is not the problem.